# Unable to read complex XML deep nested structure using Java

Tags: java, readxml

Below is my sample xml, and I am unable to read the value - Johnson Elementary School from xml using my Java code. I am able to read attributes, but not the value passed inside School ie. Johnson Elementary School. Let me know.

> Blockquote

```
<School>
   <Student>
     <name>John</name>
     <age>15</age>            
   </Student>
 Johnson Elementary School 
</School>
```

> Blockquote

Thanks
Padma

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This question is considered a poor question because you did not post the source code you are using to try and solve the problem.  Please edit your question and add the code in question.  More details on how to write a good question can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Answer (score -1):

You, probably should use method .getText() on your "School" object